# Use Play Services Location API To Get Places Around

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-architecture-components

So I want to use play service location to get current latitude and longitude of user and location updates every 3 minutes to make a request to `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search` to fetch places around and show them in a fragment.
Location updates should be received when app is visible.

I've read some articles about how to use play service location and now I am completely lost.
My question is what is the best approach to use location api?

Using FouregroundService, BackgroundService, WorkManager ?

Should it be on a background thread or the main thread?

And how should it be implemented with the Android Architecture Component?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Basically have a background service running then call an event to update the main thread (UI).

Comment: @Eenvincible I want the location updates when the user is in App and fragment is visible, should I use background service for that?!